# Recyclerview individual item click listener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

- I have a recyclerview adapter on which I create listener to handle click event.
- I implement this listener inside activity or fragment. The recyclerview items contains lot of views inside cardview.
- My problem is when I click ***img_download*** no callback occur (the log not display) but when I click on other space (not img_download) the appropriate callback occur.
- How do I know which view is clicked ?

**Adapter Code:**

```
    public class ItuneEpisodeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        TextView tvTitle;
        TextView tvDescription;
        View divider;
        ImageView img_download;

        public ItuneEpisodeViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_podcast_title);
            tvDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_description);
            divider = itemView.findViewById(R.id.divider);
            img_download = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_download);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            img_download.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (view.getId() == img_download.getId()) {
                mOnClickListener.onDownloadItemClick();
            } else {
                mOnClickListener.onItemClick(list.get(getAdapterPosition()), view);
            }
        }
    }

    public interface EpisodeClickListener {
        void onItemClick(Episode podcast, View view);
        void onDownloadItemClick();
    }
```

**Activity Implementation:**

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(Episode episode, View view) {
        PlayMediaActivity_.intent(this).extra("episode_extra", Parcels.wrap(episode)).extra("img", podcast.getCoverImage()).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDownloadItemClick() {
        Log.d("download", "yes");
    }
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**XML code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:elevation="4dp">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/md_blue_grey_100"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_podcast"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/podcast_img"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_podcast_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="Les chemins de la philosophie"
        android:textColor="@color/md_black_1000"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/img_podcast"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/img_download"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_description"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="This is a description and should be replace with the best one let"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_podcast_title"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/img_download"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_podcast_title" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_calendar"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_calendar"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_description"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_description" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_calendar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Fév. 14 2016"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/img_calendar"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/img_calendar" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_time"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_time"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_calendar"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/tv_calendar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_realisateur"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="49:50"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/img_time"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/img_time" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_download"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:tint="@color/primary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_drawer_download" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: try `if (view == img_download) { ...`

Comment: Thanks for your response @Nilu . I changed as suggested but nothing happened.

Comment: @scalp007 check pskink cmt

Comment: @pskink Thks for your response but Again nothing happened.

Comment: Can you share your xml? I think you can adjust this through xml

Comment: i think while getting `list.get(getAdapterPosition())` may be your issue @scalp007 or better you use **Toast** instead of Log to know whether view is clicked or not

Comment: @scalp007 why you are setting **`itemView.setOnClickListener(this);`**

Comment: I even made breakpoint but its not going inside img_download block when I click to the image.

Comment: I think itemView covers the img_download, so you need to adjust your layout.

Comment: @scalp007 for test case remove `itemView.setOnClickListener(this);`

Comment: Nothing is display in logcat when I click to the img_download But I have this line `EpisodeAdapter: view:android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout{1d15b53 V.E...C.. ...P.... 40,40-1400,444}` when I click to other space (not img_download) . @Nilu I made this changes because I want an event when the user click on other place (not the img_download icone)

Comment: @scalp007 than remove click listner from item and set for all controll

Comment: I told you, you need to adjust your layout, do something like relative, and have a view inside that covers the whole layout, put an ID with it and attach it to onclick. Put the image below (so it will be on TOP of the view) so you can catch the onclick of it.

Comment: Even when I remove `itemView.setOnClickListener(this);` nothing happen when I click to the image. I update my question with screenshot of the screen.

Comment: I added xml layout of my recyclerview items. @TentenPonce

Comment: I've added an answer, I've tried and tested it and it works for me. Just add focusable and clickable on your layouts to make it receive clicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, add this two code on `ConstraintLayout` (parent layout) and on your `img_download` (ImageView)

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

and instead of `itemView`, put an ID on your `ConstraintLayout` and set an `onClickListener` on it.

```
    ConstraintLayout main;
    TextView tvTitle;
    TextView tvDescription;
    View divider;
    ImageView img_download;

    public ItuneEpisodeViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        main = itemView.findViewById(R.id.main); //add this
        tvTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_podcast_title);
        tvDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_description);
        divider = itemView.findViewById(R.id.divider);
        img_download = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_download);
        main.setOnClickListener(this); //set the onclick on the parent layout
        img_download.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.img_download) {
            mOnClickListener.onDownloadItemClick();
        } else if (view.getId() == R.id.main) {
            mOnClickListener.onItemClick(list.get(getAdapterPosition()), view);
        }
    }
```

XML:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main" //add this
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:clickable="true" //add this
android:focusable="true" //add this
android:elevation="4dp">
...
...
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_download"
    android:clickable="true" //add this
    android:focusable="true" //add this
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:tint="@color/primary"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_drawer_download" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @TentenPonce . after addind these 2 lines its strangly works like a charm.